# How to change format/pattern on a string?

Tags: java, sql, regex, eclipse

I have a string like the one below and I would like to write something to check that follows the following format.

```
Insert into TABLE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) values (123, 'VALUE ' , ' ', ' ', 'XXX', 'CCC', ' ',  ' ');
```

This would be one with errors.

```
Insert into TABLE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) values (123, ''VALUE ''' , '', '', 'RED', 'FAX', '',  '');
```

As you can see the second has either an extra comma or extra quote. 
(Basically check everything inside the values parentheses, the insert never changes. )

I would like to check for the wrong pattern and edit it on the fly. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you allowing users to enter SQL as plain text? Because that's a no-no.

Comment: no! Just have a huge wall of text to fix.

Comment: If it's identical SQL, split the string on " values ", take split[1] and split that on commas, then count the number of apostrophes in each split.

Comment: idk if that works for you but if you need to check just simple cases maybe a regex like `"Insert into TABLE\\(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H\\) values \\(\\d+, '[^']+' , ' ', ' ', '[^']+', '[^']+', ' ',  ' '\\);"` is enough? (It won't let correctly escaped `'` pass though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

```
^[^(]*table\([^)]*\)[^(]*?Values\s*
(\((?:(?:[^';\n\r]*|'[^']*')\s*(?:(?=\))|,)\s*)*\))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regex will do the following:

- Find lines starting with a structure that looks like  `Insert into TABLE( .... ) values`
- Verifies the `values` section contains a comma delimited list of values which are only

  - strings not enclosed in quotes like `123`
  - strings enclosed in single quotes like `'red'`
- allow white space to surround any delimiting comma
- allow quoted strings to contain commas like `'This, value has a comma'`

**Notes:**

- If the regex does not match your string then there is a problem with your source string
- I recommend using the following flags for this: Case insenstive.

## Examples

**Live example**

In this example I'm using the multi line, global, and ignore white space options. To better illustrate how it functions.

https://regex101.com/r/iW9gI7/1

**Source String**

The last line here is not valid

```
Insert into TABLE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) values (123);
Insert into TABLE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) values (123, 'VALUE ', ' ', ' ', 'XXX', 'CCC', ' ', ' ');
Insert into TABLE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) values (123, 'VAL,UE ' , ' ', ' ', 'XXX', 'CCC', ' ',  ' ');
Insert into TABLE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) values (123, ''VALUE ''' , '', '', 'RED', 'FAX', '',  '')
```

**Valid matches**

```
Insert into TABLE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) values (123)
Insert into TABLE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) values (123, 'VALUE ', ' ', ' ', 'XXX', 'CCC', ' ', ' ')
Insert into TABLE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) values (123, 'VAL,UE ' , ' ', ' ', 'XXX', 'CCC', ' ',  ' ')
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^(]*                    any character except: '(' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  table                    'table'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^)]*                    any character except: ')' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^(]*?                   any character except: '(' (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Values                   'Values'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^';\n\r]*               any character except: ''', ';', '\n'
                                 (newline), '\r' (carriage return) (0
                                 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                                 times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (0 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        ,                        ','
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (0 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If there was more points to give you I would. Perfect explanation man. Thanks alot.